# How to insert ₹(Special characters) into Database

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

Currently i tried by modifying my property file to insert those special characters.But its inserting as a question mark instead of ₹ Symbol please find below changes.

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbName?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&useUnicode=true&character_set_server=utf8mb4

My Entity column definition

```
@Column(name = "question", columnDefinition = "TEXT")
private String question;
```

**I tried by doing**

1.change in column definition to "nvarchar" i got hibernate error.

2.In mysql changed column definition to `ALTER TABLE table CHANGE column column VARCHAR(190) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;` 
referred, to change mysql tables definitions [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43629756/storing-emojis-in-mysql-database)

In case of any modification or mistake help me.

Comment: Look at `@Nationalized` annotation, it may help your problem [Annotation Type Nationalized](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Nationalized.html)

Comment: Hey thank you so much it's working after adding @nationalized. Please can you add it as a answer so that i can accept answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at `@Nationalized` annotation, it may help your problem [Annotation Type Nationalized](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Nationalized.html)

```java
@Nationalized
@Column(name = "question", columnDefinition = "TEXT")
private String question;
```

Comment: Yes it worked before that required to do ALTER TABLE test_tb MODIFY COLUMN col text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL; otherwise will throw getNstring() error.Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Change the character encoding to utf8_general_ci by,

```
ALTER TABLE test_tb MODIFY COLUMN col VARCHAR(255)
    CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL;
```

And then,

```
insert into test_tb values("₹");
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. When i try to insert from spring boot with the Column TEXT it's converting to ? i have changed to utf8_general_ci NOT NULL; in mysql but still same issue